# change default icon outlook-addin

Tags: outlook-addin

I try to change the defaut icon of y outlook add-in. By defaut it's blue icon [image: defaut icon]

I changed every logo in my images folder. When I would like add my add-in I see the correct logo [image]

But on Outlook, I have again the old logo [[image]]

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFwMy.png) 
I tried to clean and rebuild the solution, but it didn't change anything. I don't understand why I have always the old logo. I don't know where this old logo come from

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in your manifest file this:

```
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="your URL to image"/>
 <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="your URL to image" />
```

The image have to be 128x128 .

If you have compose and read tags you need also have this:

```
             <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
              </Icon>
```

When icon16,icon32,icon80 is inside the source tag:

```
<Resources>
  <bt:Images>
      <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="your URL to image"/>
  </bt:Images>
</Resources>
```

You can see full example and explanation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/manifests

Comment: Note that even when everything is configured correctly, the icons will not render in the tray if running the add-in locally.