# Can't change the default icon in Excel on the Home ribbon

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

I can't change the default icon on the Home Tab by editing the manifest.

I found this ... [change default icon outlook-addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47382337/change-default-icon-outlook-addin)

Which suggested that I add the tag HighResolutionIconUrl to the manifest but that doesn't work.

I added `<HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button64x64.png" />`

to my manifest. The instructions on [change default icon outlook-addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47382337/change-default-icon-outlook-addin) suggest that it must be 128x128 but I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/highresolutioniconurl which indicates for non-outlook it should be 64x64. I've tried both, the 128x128 won't compile and the 64x64 doesn't change the default icon.

UPDATE

When side loading the project the icon shows up on the ribbon correctly. It is only when testing the app from Visual Studio that the icon is incorrect.

Comment: I suggest you to use Visual studio code or any jetbrians ide

Comment: One thing which I would like to tell you is icon should be always served from https and try a full path please. In my case:  `<HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://azurewebsites.net/assets/image_300.png"/>`

Comment: Did you try serving your icon from cloud as mentioned above? Does it work

Comment: If by "serving your icon from the cloud" you mean that it is located on a web server instead of my local PC, then yes that works. Thanks.

Comment: Yup. Glad it worked 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting here as a solution for anyone who has the same problem:

**Solution:**

Icon should be always served from https and try a full path please. 
In my case I was serving from Azure cloud. It can be of AWS S3 or GCP or any other secure location.

```
<HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://azurewebsites.net/assets/image_300.png"/>
```

Hope it should work definitely.